# Issue with data scraping from website with token

Tags: python, url, python-requests, token

I'm new with website data scraping so I have some questions which require answers. I've been looking for an answer for a while but doesn't work well for me.

I'm trying to get covid-19 data from this website: https://ncov.vncdc.gov.vn/viet-nam-full.html

Normally I use Inspect in the browser to fetch the API URL from the website, which worked.

But for the past few days they seem to added some kind of token, which still allow me to see the data on the website but not possible to fetch the data with get request without the token.

For example:
[The API link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljtwi.jpg)

In the past, I could use the following code to get data and modify parameter to change the data range if necessary.

```
import requests
url = 'https://ncov.vncdc.gov.vn/v2/vietnam/report-epi-province?start_time=2021-04-27&end_time=2021-09-25&province_ids=&district_ids=&get_time=1632547194551'
response = requests.get(url).json()

#change parameters
url = 'https://ncov.vncdc.gov.vn/v2/vietnam/report-epi-province?start_time={}&end_time={}&province_ids=&district_ids=&get_time=1632547194551'.format(date1,date2)
```

But now it requires me to input some kind of token which I fetched from the request headers in Inspect mode to get the same data, and it's not possible to change the date to get data anymore.

For example:
[x-data-token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2tpB.jpg)

```
import requests
url = 'https://ncov.vncdc.gov.vn/v2/vietnam/report-epi-province?start_time=2021-04-27&end_time=2021-09-25&province_ids=&district_ids=&get_time=1632547194551'
headers = {'x-data-token':'1cbcaa3e3be7546058beb7a981921784'}
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers).json()
```

When I try to change the date in the url it just returns 'Token not valid'.

What I need help with is how I can get this token automatically with Python (I don't want to open the browser and copy the token everytime) and get the data with different parameter values (the date).

If anyone can show me a better way to do it. I would be very graceful.
This is my first post and I'm new to this so I tried my best to explain the situation.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `x-data-token` header is created in the [main JavaScript file](https://ncov.vncdc.gov.vn/main.2c600a5f3ab5c630e1fd.chunk.js). Unfortunately, that means you would have to evaluate the JavaScript code to generate the token. Here are some tools that may help.

- [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/)
- [dukpy](https://github.com/amol-/dukpy)
- [SlimIt](https://slimit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)